# how to append a into a combo value with space

Tags: jquery, select, combobox

I want to fill a select dynamically with jQuery.

Some values have spaces, and it doesn't fill the select correctly.

```
    var value = "01 02 020";
    var name = "name";

    console.log(value + " " + name); //that's correct

    var optionSelect ="<option value=" + value + ">" + name + "</option>"
    $(optionSelect).appendTo($('select[name="comboName"]'));
```

When the combo is filled, it is:

```
<option value="01" 02="" 020="">name</option>
```

How can I fix this to get:

```
<option value="01 02 020">name</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the value  with quotes, since the value contains space.

```
var optionSelect ="<option value='" + value + "'>" + name + "</option>"
//                              -^----     ----^-
```